# Fragment cannot show and app will break down

Tags: android, android-fragments, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-arrayadapter

I try to write a fragment to list the user from firebase,
however, it cannot show the list and then the app broken down.

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?
below is the code:

```
public class FriendListFragment extends Fragment{

private ArrayList<String> mUsernames = new ArrayList<>();

private ListView mFriendList;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_friendlist,container,false);

    //FirebaseDatabase mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

    DatabaseReference mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
            //.getReferenceFromUrl("https://game-frontier.firebaseio.com/");

    mFriendList = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.friendList);

    final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mUsernames);


    //final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mUsernames);
    //mFriendList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mUsernames));

    mFriendList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    mRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            mUsernames.add(value);
            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    return rootView;

}
}
```

the error logcat is below:

```
D/FA: Connected to remote service
V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 1
W/PathParser: Points are too far apart 4.000000596046461
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/UncaughtException: com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert value of type java.util.HashMap to String
                     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbtg.zzaF(Unknown Source)
                     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbtg.zzb(Unknown Source)
                     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbtg.zza(Unknown Source)
                     at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source)
                     at game_frontier_fragment.FriendListFragment$1.onChildAdded(FriendListFragment.java:58)
                     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbox.zza(Unknown Source)
                     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqx.zzZS(Unknown Source)
                     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbra$1.run(Unknown Source)
                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:234)
                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5526)
                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

D/FA: Logging event (FE): _ae, Bundle[{_o=crash, _sc=MainActivity, _si=-9082221781176828208, timestamp=1487772508300, fatal=1}]
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.gamefrontier.jk.gamefrontier, PID: 14745
                  com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert value of type java.util.HashMap to String
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbtg.zzaF(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbtg.zzb(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbtg.zza(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source)
                      at game_frontier_fragment.FriendListFragment$1.onChildAdded(FriendListFragment.java:58)
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbox.zza(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqx.zzZS(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbra$1.run(Unknown Source)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:234)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5526)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
I/DpmTcmClient: RegisterTcmMonitor from: com.android.okhttp.TcmIdleTimerMonitor
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 14745 SIG: 9
Application terminated.

Comment: Yes, when I click the list fragment, it will be crashed

Comment: And do you understand what the errors are telling you? `FriendListFragment.java:58` is where the error exists